# Solve: $3x(x+y-2)=2y$ with $y(x+y-1)=9x$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

This is a question from my Regional Mathematics Olympiad. It is from the topic- polynomials.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @TheDragonborn Hello Dragonborn. I tried to put y=(3x^2-6x)/(2-3x). I got the correct answer but it was very lengthy. I want a trick/ shorter method.

Comment: Is this a current/live problem? If so, I believe it is not right to provide an answer.

Comment: @Integrand no RMO is not live right now

Comment: @Integrand I'm sorry. It is from my mock test (dated 19th June 2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both equations,

$$3x(x+y-2)y(x+y-1) = 18yx$$

Cancelling $x$ and $y$, we obtain a solutions $x=0$ and $y=0$

Next assume $x+y=t$ and solve quadratic.

$$(t-2)(t-1)=6$$

$$(t-4)(t+1)=0$$

$$x+y = 4,x+y+1=0$$

Thus the solutions must be all points on the lines $x+y=4$ , $x+y+1=0$ , $x=0$ and $y=0$

Finally, look at the respective equations.

$$3x(x+y-2)=2y$$

Here if we check with the line $x=0$

$$y=0$$

So, one solution is $(0,0)$.

Note we don't need to check with $y=0$ as its already solved here. Also this is satisfying the other given equation.

Next check the same with the other line obtained...(i.e. solve $x+y = 4,-1$ with the given equations) and take the common points as your answer.

I think you can take it from here..

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a doubt. The answer given is (0,0);(1,3);(2/7,-9/7). Why is that so?

Comment: I am sorry @AnsheekaGupta I forgot to add a step where you take intersections of lines occurring in both equations....Edit on the way

Comment: I still can't understand. These equations will have parallel representation so how can they have a common section?

Comment: @AnsheekaGupta we just found that whatever solutions will be there, they will lie on the parallel lines obtained, we finally have to check where our lines and the equations given intersect.....and also check if a solution satisfies both equations

Answer (score 1):

First of all,if any one of $x,y$ is $0$,then the other one should also be $0$.
$(x,y)=(0,0)$ is indeed a solution.
Now,multiply them together to arrive at,
$(x+y-1)^2-(x+y-1)-6=0$ which gives $x+y-1=-2,3$

Then,substitute this back into the equation to get the solutions:
$(1,3)$ and $(\frac{2}{7},\frac{-9}{7})$